# Calculated value not getting in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to calculate `var packprice` + `var packprices` + `var ala` Which is getting in for loop. I'm getting the all values in console but in `tprice` addition is not getting. Please help.

```
$( "#get_total" ).click(function() {
    alert('calculation pending');
    var idSelector = function() { return this.value; };
    var packprices = 0;
    var packprice = 0;
    var c = $(":checkbox:checked").map(idSelector).get();

    for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        // console.log(c[i]);
        // console.log(parseInt($(".longduration_price" + c[i]).val()));
        if($(".duration_status" + c[i]).is(':checked'))
        {
            var packprice = !isNaN(parseInt($(".longduration_price" + c[i]).val())) ? parseInt($(".longduration_price" + c[i]).val()) : 0 ;
            console.log(packprice);
        }else{
            var packprices = !isNaN(parseInt($(".packpriceone" + c[i]).val())) ? parseInt($(".packpriceone" + c[i]).val()) : 0 ;
            console.log(packprices); 
        }
        var ala = parseInt($("#alacartprice").val());
        var tprice = packprice + packprices + ala;
    }

    console.log(tprice);

    $("#totalprice").val(tprice);
});
```

Comment: Please can you post your html as well or share the jsfiddle, Its easy to debug

Comment: Actually there is lots of code getting all values with php from database directly. So I'm not able to add whole code here.

Comment: What is the value you are getting other than the desired result?

Comment: I'm getting last checked value in console when I calculate

Comment: It's hard to figure out your problem. Your code looks fine. Declaration outside/inside the loop doesn't matter. Are you getting '0' as o/p or some concatenated value like '12+234'?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `tprice` outside of loop and add results to `tprice` as below.

```
$( "#get_total" ).click(function() {
alert('calculation pending');
var idSelector = function() { return this.value; };
var packprices = 0;
var packprice = 0;
var c = $(":checkbox:checked").map(idSelector).get();
var tprice = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    // console.log(c[i]);
    // console.log(parseInt($(".longduration_price" + c[i]).val()));
    if($(".duration_status" + c[i]).is(':checked'))
    {
        var packprice = !isNaN(parseInt($(".longduration_price" + c[i]).val())) ? parseInt($(".longduration_price" + c[i]).val()) : 0 ;
        console.log(packprice);
    }else{
        var packprices = !isNaN(parseInt($(".packpriceone" + c[i]).val())) ? parseInt($(".packpriceone" + c[i]).val()) : 0 ;
        console.log(packprices); 
    }
    var ala = parseInt($("#alacartprice").val());
    tprice += packprice + packprices + ala;
}

console.log(tprice);

$("#totalprice").val(tprice);
});
```

Comment: Getting right ans when I clicked outside checkbox but when I checked duration_status which is in if the value is getting doubled.

Comment: We would need more context to understand what you are trying to implement.

Comment: now the total price is getting correct If both inner checkbox are checked or unchecked. If one is not checked that time the value is double of inner checkbox

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by inner checkbox, you haven't shared the HTML

Answer (score 0):

you must define the variable before the for loop

```js
$( "#get_total" ).click(function() {
 
  alert('calculation pending');
  var idSelector = function() {
    return this.value;
  };
  var packprices = 0;
  var packprice = 0;
  var c = $(":checkbox:checked").map(idSelector).get();
  var tprice = 0

  for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    // console.log(c[i]);
    // console.log(parseInt($(".longduration_price" + c[i]).val()));
    if ($(".duration_status" + c[i]).is(':checked')) {
      var packprice = !isNaN(parseInt($(".longduration_price" + c[i]).val())) ? parseInt($(".longduration_price" + c[i]).val()) : 0;
      console.log(packprice);
    } else {
      var packprices = !isNaN(parseInt($(".packpriceone" + c[i]).val())) ? parseInt($(".packpriceone" + c[i]).val()) : 0;
      console.log(packprices);
    }
    var ala = parseInt($("#alacartprice").val());
    tprice = packprice + packprices + ala;
  }

  console.log(tprice);

  $("#totalprice").val(tprice);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I need all calculation on button click. There is no click in your above called

Comment: code will have first line as $( "#get_total" ).click(function() {  , I am editing my answer

Comment: Not working..I'm getting value only last check checkbox. I'm getting all the values in console. but not getting total

Answer (score 0):

we assume you have span element like follow:

```
 <span id="totalprice"></span>
```

now you by below code you can set value that declare out of loop

```
var currentValue = parseInt($("#totalprice").text(),tprice);
```